# Can I learn Quantum Programming and then go back to learn the Mathematics / Physics behind it later?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, resource-request, classical-computing

Learning from the ground up (while great) is an overdose of the mathematics behind quantum computing and is taking way too long to grasp.

I have a Computer Science / Programming background. I am happy to learn the programming aspects and then go back and learn the math behind it or learn the background math whenever it is necessary while programming.

I started with MacMahon's book and now on Nielsen and Chuang.. but I feel it is taking longer to get to the application layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quantum computing is completely different paradigm in comparison with classical computers. Therefore an approach to programming quantum computers is different as well. It is not only about learning a new programming language but also about understanding underlying technology. Currently, there is only a little abstraction between quatum algorithms (programs) and quantum hardware. Nowadays, programming a quantum computer is similar to approach used in 1950's when computers were programmed in assembler or even microinstructions (what is different that we have common quantum gates).

There are some higher programming languages (for example Qiskit based on Python) helping you to load data into a quantum computer and postprocess results. However, quantum algorithm is still expressed on quantum gates level.

**Overall, to be able to program quantum computer and understand why you do so, you should learn at least basic mathematical background of quantum computing.**

Comment: Thanks so much. It feels like going through a 3-4 year Graduation Process :)

Comment: @SudeeptMaharana: I was able to learn basics of QC in one year. I would recommend to start with introduction on IBM Q site as Nielsen and Chuang book is a little bit difficult for beginers. I would also recommend this book: **Christine Corbett Moran: Mastering Quantum Computing with IBM QX: Explore the world of quantum computing using the Quantum Composer and Qiskit.**

Comment: That's really helpful. Thank You.

Comment: @SudeeptMaharana, I also recommend https://quantum.country/, which has four articles in increasing difficulty with the final one being a primer in quantum mechanics.

Comment: Thanks, Amir. I will.